# Correlated subquery friends

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
select friends_of_first.friend
from (
    select id2 as friend from friend_relastionship where id1 = '4'
    union 
    select id1 as friend from friend_relastionship where id2 = '4'
    ) friends_of_first
join (
    select id2 as friend from friend_relastionship where id1 = '7'
    union 
    select id1 as friend from friend_relastionship where id2 = '7'
    ) friends_of_second
on friends_of_first.friend = friends_of_second.friend;
```

This query finds the mutual friends between users 4 and 7.

I want to use this as a basis of finding all pairs of mutual friends inside the table `friend_relastionship` so that I can select the top pairs with the most mutual friends. My understanding is that I can run this on every pairing with a correlated subquery but I am unsure how.

The table is designed in such a way that id1 < id2  and if a friendship exists between 1 and 7 then it is listed as 1,7 and never 7,1. So a friendship appears once.

Here is a sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48eb0/1

In this sqlfiddle it should display

```
 USER1      USER2      COUNT
     3          4          3
     6          7          2
     4         45          2
     2          7          2
     2          6          2
     1          2          2
     1         45          2
     0          2          2
```

...

Indicating that 3 and 4 should be friends, as they have 3 mutual friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another shot using the data in SQL Fiddle:

`select a.friend1 as ID1, b.friend1 as ID2, count(distinct a.friend2) as connections
from ((select id1 as friend1, id2 as friend2
from friend_relastionship)
UNION
(select id2 as friend1, id1 as friend2
from friend_relastionship))a
join ((select id1 as friend1, id2 as friend2
from friend_relastionship)
UNION
(select id2 as friend1, id1 as friend2
from friend_relastionship))b on a.friend2 = b.friend2
where a.friend1 < b.friend1
group by ID1, ID2
having connections > 1
order by connections desc`

You should consider reviewing how this data is stored or making it more query friendly by adding the UNION statement below as view.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the table structure so you will have to replace my column names with the actual column names, but this should work:

`Select fof1.connection, fof1.friend, fof2.friend
from friend_relationship fof1
join friend_relationship fof2 on fof1.connection = fof2.connection
where fof1.friend < fof2.friend`

You can then just do a count on each connection to see who has the most rows.

Comment: Connection is the friend that id1 and id2 have in common.

Comment: I dont see where that is coming from. I know that connection is the result of my postesd query but how do I get this query to run on every combination ?

Comment: Thought you had a third column that was the connection, or in this case the friend of both friends. Taking a look at your sqlfiddle.